# tfidf TfidfVectorizer to data frame Shape error

Tags: scikit-learn

I have some training data that am I trying to calculate the tif-idf values for:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

file_name = '../../data/spam.csv'
spam_data_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

spam_data_df['target'] = np.where(spam_data_df['target']=='spam',1,0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(spam_data_df['text'], 
                                                      spam_data_df['target'],
                                                      test_size=0.3, 
                                                      random_state=0)

X_train_list = X_train.tolist()

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer() 

tfidf_vectorizer_fit = tfidf_vectorizer.fit(X_train_list)
tfidf_vectorizer_vectors = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(X_train_list)

feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()


tfidf_vectorizer_dense = tfidf_vectorizer_vectors.todense()
tfidf_dense_list = tfidf_vectorizer_dense.tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vectorizer_dense, 
                  index=feature_names, 
                  columns=["tfidf"]).reset_index()
```

What I am looking for is to contract a table that looks like the following:

```
token      tfidf
Mathews    0.99343
tait       0.02342 
edwards    0.45453
anderson   0.21216
```

Here is an excerpt of the data:

```
text,target
"Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...",ham
Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...,ham
Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts 21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's,spam
U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...,ham
"Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though",ham
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3900, 7098), indices imply (7098, 1)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_vectorizer_dense.T, 
                  index=feature_names).reset_index() 
                  # columns=["tfidf"])
```

It will return something like

```py
token            0        1        2  ...    3899
Mathews    0.99343  0.12421  0.00000  ... 0.48674
tait       0.02342  0.00000  0.00000  ... 0.12421
edwards    0.45453  0.40727  0.09323  ... 0.00000
anderson   0.21216  0.30638  0.44592  ... 0.32154
...
```

#### Explanation

You have 3900 texts with 7098 `tfidf` features.

```bash
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3900, 7098), indices imply (7098, 1)
```

The error implies that there is a mismatch between

- shape of `tfidf_vectorizer_dense` - `(3900, 7098)`
- shape set by `index=feature_names` `(7098)` and `column=["tfidf"]` `(1)` - `(7098, 1)`.

Your goal is to match them so both are (7098, 3900).

You can do a transpose, `tfidf_vectorizer_dense.T`. After the transposition, it will have a shape of `(7098, 3900)`. This aligns with the length of `index`.

For columns, you can just remove `column=`.